# Connecting to ES using python script

Tags: python, elasticsearch, pyes, pyelasticsearch

I am trying to connect and retrieve data from a ES engine.

I am using the following script:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch as ES

print "Setup connection..."
es=ES(['http://elasticsearch......com:9200/cuevents-2014.34,cuevents-2014.33/_search?pretty'])
print "Done!"

print "Count number of users..."
print es.count(index='cuevents-2014.34')
```

But I am getting the following messaged returned instead.

```
Setup connection...
No handlers could be found for logger "elasticsearch"
Done!
Count number of users...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/es.py", line 8, in <module>
    print es.count(index='cuevents-2014.34')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/elasticsearch/client/utils.py", line 68, in _wrapped
    return func(*args, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/elasticsearch/client/__init__.py", line 622, in count
    params=params, body=body)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/elasticsearch/transport.py", line 284, in perform_request
    status, headers, data = connection.perform_request(method, url, params, body, ignore=ignore, timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/elasticsearch/connection/http_urllib3.py", line 51, in perform_request
    raise ConnectionError('N/A', str(e), e)
elasticsearch.exceptions.ConnectionError: ConnectionError(('Connection aborted.', gaierror(-2, 'Name or service not known'))) caused by: ProtocolError(('Connection aborted.', gaierror(-2, 'Name or service not known')))
```

I am trying to connect and return the number of documents in the index cuevents-2014.34

Comment: Sounds obvious, but are you sure index cuevents-2014.34 exists?

Comment: Yes I cam sure the index exist.

Comment: When I use the following i get a response from Marvel- Sense interface.                                                                              'code'                                                    curl -XGET "http://elasticsearch....com:9200/cuevents-2014.34,cuevents-2014.33/_search?pretty" -d'
{
    
  "size": 0,
  "aggregations": {
    "coeunt": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "site_name",
        "size": 0
      }
    }
  }
}''code'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I looked at your code again more closely. The Elasticsearch constructor needs to be pointed to the root URL - you're not supposed to specify indexes on the URL.

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch as ES

print "Setup connection..."
es=ES(['http://elasticsearch......com:9200/'])
print "Done!"

print "Count number of users..."
print es.count(index='cuevents-2014.34')
```

See http://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.org/en/master/api.html#elasticsearch

If you want to limit access to only certain indexes - Elasticsearch does not provide access control at all. You can do it via URL rewriting on a reverse proxy.